# Do any of these functions solve the following partial differential equation?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

The partial differential equation is $$u_x-u_y+3u=1$$ and the possible choices are:

$$a)u(x,y)=\frac{1}{3}+xe^{3y}+ye^{3y}$$
$$b)u(x,y)=\frac{1}{3}+x^2+y^2$$
$$c)u(x,y)= e^{xy}+1$$
$$d)u(x,y)= x + y+ 1$$
$$e)\text{none of the above}$$

I worked with each of the four functions and I realized that it's really between b) and e). For b) $u_x=2x$ and $u_y=2y$ when I plug it into the partial differential equation I get: $$2x-2y+1+3x^2+3y^2=1$$ rearranging things gives: $$3x^2+2x+1+3y^2-2y-1=0$$ This is where I'm stuck. My first thought would be to group the terms like: $$(3x^2+2x+1)+(3y^2-2y-1)=0$$ but in just looking at the first term I see that I am going to get imaginary solutions for x. I know that I will at least get values for $x,y$ but this entire course is about being in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so it makes me believe that the answer is e.

The answer key doesn't come out until tomorrow so I have no clue what the actual answer is.

Comment: For $u = u(x,y)$ to be a solution of a PDE, plugging this in to the PDE must result in an equation that is true for **all** $x$ and $y$, (or at least all in some domain where you want the solution to be valid), not just for $(x,y)$ on some curve.

Comment: So it's moreso if I can algebraically reduce the left side to be equal to one, not If I can find a value for x and y. Is that correct?

Comment: It is easy to obtain the general solution $u(x,y)=\frac{1}{3}+e^{-3x}F(x+y)$ for arbitrary function $F$ thanks to the metod of characteristics. Then obviously only option a) is consistent with the general solution.

Comment: Yeah, I realized I wasn't doing the chain rule correctly for option a.